# uv map not mapping

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, workflow

When I seam and uv map this stool, the faces overlap on the image section. I recently switched from v 2.74 to 2.64 to model for another program. Help baby cakes? [image: This is that it looks like.]

[image]

This here is me attempting to just uv map the two sides of this stool, where as the top image is me trying to uv map the whole thing.

Comment: I don't think I get what you want . . .

Comment: If you upload a photo of the bench you're trying to model, it might help us help you improve your question, and give you a better answer.. I think I understand what you're trying to do , but lack enough information to provide a good answer.

Comment: are you asking why the texture is not displaying in the 3D view? it you are change the shading mode (in the 3D header) to textured.